# Proper Checkbox linebreaks

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I want to create a checkbox as described in the official TCPF tutorial [here](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_014.phps) (Newsletter). The Text should be shown right after the Checkbox in the SAME line, not the next. For debugging I draw a border around the cell.
Code:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, '2.4 Welche Arten von Abscheideranlagen betreiben Sie?', $border, $align = 'L', $fill = false, $ln = 1, $x = '', $y = '', $reseth = true, $stretch = 0, $ishtml = false, $autopadding = true, $maxh = 0, $valign = 'T', $fitcell = false);
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->setFormDefaultProp(array('lineWidth' => 1, 'borderStyle' => 'solid', 'fillColor' => array(255, 255, 200), 'strokeColor' => array(255, 128, 128)));
$pdf->CheckBox('separator_light_liquid', 5, $dataset->separator_light_liquid, $prop = array(), $opt = array(), $onvalue = true, $x = '', $y = '', $js = false);
$pdf->Cell(35, 0, 'Leichtflüssigkeit', 1, $ln = 0, $align = 'L', $fill = false, $link = '', $stretch = 0, $ignore_min_height = false, $calign = 'T', $valign = 'M');
$pdf->Ln(5);
```

PDF-Output:[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaraound, I generate a cell with borders. If the box should be "checked" there will be written a 'X' into the box. Else nothing is

```
($value ? $value = 'X' : $value = null);
$pdf->Cell(5, $h = 5, $txt = $value, $border = 1, $ln = 0, $align = '', 0, $link = '', $stretch = 1, $ignore_min_height = false, $calign = 'T', $valign = 'M');
$pdf->Cell(0, $h = 6, $txt = $label, $border = 0, $ln = 1, $align = '', 0, $link = '', $stretch = 1, $ignore_min_height = false, $calign = 'T', $valign = 'M');
```

PDF-Output:

[image]